# platform-tools\adb.exe: Comman d failed with exit code 3221226356

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

When I run (Ionic run android )ionic project, it build success but there was an issue in deploying to device.

[this is the error in my cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVkZI.png)

Comment: Insert the text error in your post, dont' use the screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps

1. Create virtual device from android adb manager.
2. Open virtual device(emulator).
3. Open termainal and check your emulator is connected or
   not. `$ adb devices`.
4. If your emulator is connected then open
   terminal and  go to your root folder of project.
5. run followingcommand

   $ ionic run android

I hope its work for you