# "cordova run android" suddenly stopped working, ends with error message

Tags: cordova

Running "cordova run android" suddenly stopped working. It now ends with this error message:

```sh
Failed to execute shell command "cat,/proc/cpuinfo"" on device: Error: adb: Command failed with exit code 3221226356
```

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling, trying different versions, but nothing seems to work. I have no clue what might have changed.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42641025/platform-tools-adb-exe-comman-d-failed-with-exit-code-3221226356

Comment: Tried it. Doesn't change anything unfortunately.